# Ignite and MySQL - Unexpected number of updated entries

Tags: java, mysql, spring, ignite

I have cache

```
@Bean
  CacheConfiguration persistenceCacheConfiguration(
    CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<Long, SequencesEntity> storeFactory) {
    CacheConfiguration<Long, SequencesEntity> configuration = new CacheConfiguration<>(
      PERSISTENCE_CACHE_NAME);
    configuration.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, SequencesEntity.class);
    configuration.setReadThrough(true);
    configuration.setWriteThrough(true);
    configuration.setCacheStoreFactory(storeFactory);
    configuration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
    return configuration;
  }
```

and i use MySQL Database.

When I update the data in the cache, the Ignite executes the following method and query:

```
CacheAbstractJdbcStore.write
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, stream_name, value) VALUES (1,'my',100000000001) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stream_name = VALUES(stream_name), value = VALUES(value)
```

It returns 2 row(s) affected. It correct - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated.

And the ignite writes to the log WARN (it's ignite source code):

```
if (updCnt != 1)
                        U.warn(log, "Unexpected number of updated entries [table=" + em.fullTableName() +
                            ", entry=" + entry + "expected=1, actual=" + updCnt + "]");
```

I believe that updating the record is correct behavior and I do not want to see a warning in the logs. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a bug. Filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-8550 for that.
Other than that, I can only suggest you to ignore this warning.